# Motion of molecules of an ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, molecules

Why does an ideal gas show only translatory motion and not vibratory motion?

Comment: If you neglect the internal degrees of freedom of the molecules then what does vibratory motion mean?

Comment: Ask yourself:  what is an ideal gas?  Clarify in your mind what is meant by ideal gas.  It's important to have that clear in your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal gas particle is considered to be a non-interacting point mass i.e. a zero-dimensional object. As such it has no internal degrees of freedom - it cannot rotate or vibrate. The only degrees of freedom it has are the three translational ones.

Comment: If you define an ideal gas as such one that obeys the ideal gas law or such that its internal energy depends only on the temperature, then it may well be formed by polyatomic molecules. The molecules themselves are considered non-interacting point masses and their translational degrees of freedom are responsible for pressure and temperature. However, their vibrations give different specific heats (or adiabatic constants) for ideal gases.

Answer (score 0):

By definition an ideal gas is a gas composed by non-interacting point particles moving randomly. It is not meant to represent a real gas, but a simplification of a gas with more complex interactions, such as vibrations and rotations. For example, most real gases at room temperature can be approximated by an ideal gas, since only translational degrees of freedom contribute to their energy.

Such simplification (non-interacting particles) allows us to obtain macroscopic quantities such as temperature, pressure, etc. relatively easy, and thus is one of the first concepts one sees when studying statistical mechanics. To clarify, let's write the hamiltonian for an ideal gas if $N$ particles:

$$H=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{p_i ^2}{2m}$$

This is just the sum of kinetic energies for all the particles (no interactions). Conversely, if we consider other degrees of freedom such as vibration and rotation, our hamiltonian becomes:

$$H=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{p_i ^2}{2m} + H_V + H_R$$

The addition of such contributions complicates computations and obtaining macroscopic quantities becomes harder. In conclusion, an ideal gas is just a concept, an approximation of real gases which in a lot of situations becomes handy as it predicts their macroscopic behavior quite well.

Hope this helps!